# Meta Tag for Mobile and Desktop Browser detection

Tags: desktop, meta-tags, mobile-browser

I want to know is there any way where I can detect whether site is opened on mobile browser or desktop browser ?
so based on that contact us/phone number link will make call (for mobile browser) or link to contact us page(for desktop browser).

Comment: There's no meta tag, but checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/javascript-solution-to-detect-mobile-browser.  As far as making a call after the fact, I doubt phones security models will allow that.

Comment: You can detect the user agent (either in JS or on the server using, e.g.,  PHP) and display according code.

Comment: Thank you i got solution for it in PHP.